# Is there an obvious reason this loops endlessly?

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, nodes, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing an AST and Node class.

Basically, the AST has a vector of Nodes, 'Nodes'. Each Node item in this vector can have its owns children inside a vector of Node called, 'Children', each child is imply another Node object which can have its own children, too, etc..

I am writing a simply printable version of the AST, reading all nodes and printing them with respective padding (spaces, or whatever other string or character), for instance:

```
NODE_EXPR
         NODE_INT_LIT
         NODE_OPERATOR_PLUS
         NODE_INT_LIT

NODE_IF_STMT
            NODE_EXPR
                     NODE_INT_LIT
                     NODE_OPERATOR_TRUTH_EQ
                     NODE_INT_LIT
            NODE_BODY
                     NODE_KYWD_RETURN
```

etc. Just a basic branching structure.

Now, the nodes just added to some AST using `ast.addNode(someNodeObjectByValue);`, will make it's parent (a pointer to a Node in the AST) equal `nullptr`, because it's parent is the AST itself. Whereas nodes added using the overloaded `ast.addNode(someNodeObjectByValue, pointerToParentNode);`will obviously make the provided node the newly added node's parent.

---

### PROBLEM CODE

The code below is the problem. It should set the temporary node reference being worked with to its parent once it's done, so that the next iteration can operate, and should eventually "break", when the current node object has no parent.

```
string Node::getPadding(string padding) {
size_t len = 0;
Node* child = this;

    while (child->hasParent()) {
        len += child->Parent->getNodeNodeTypeString().length();
        child = child->Parent;
        //keeps looping :/
    }
    return StringManip::repeatString(padding, len);
}
```

I know this is something stupid,please ask for any code (it's quite a short *.cpp for the whole thing, but I didn't want to included unnecessarily.

EDIT: The whole (very short) */cpp

```
//**C AST
void AST::addNode(Node node) {
    node._nodeID = NodeCount();
    node.Parent = nullptr;
    node.ParentAST = this;
    Nodes.push_back(node);
}
void AST::addNode(Node node, size_t parentNode) {
    node._nodeID = NodeCount();
    node.ParentAST = this;
    node.Parent = getNodeWithID(parentNode);
    node.Parent->Children.push_back(node);
}
Node* AST::getNodeWithID(size_t id) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Nodes.size(); i++)
        if (Nodes[i].NodeID() == id) return &Nodes[i];

}
void AST::popEndNode() {
    Nodes.pop_back();
}
void AST::deleteNode(size_t nodeID) {
    Nodes.erase(Nodes.begin() + nodeID);
}
size_t AST::NodeCount() {
    return Nodes.size();
}


//**C Node
string Node::getNodeNodeTypeString() {
    switch (NodeType) {
        ...
    case NodeType::TOKENTYPE_INT_LIT:
        return "TOKENTYPE_INT_LIT";
    break;
        ...
    default:
        return "UNKOWN_TOKEN_TYPE";
    }
}
bool Node::hasChildren() {
    return (Children.size() != 0);
}
size_t Node::childCount() {
    return Children.size();
}

string Node::getPadding(string padding) {
   //^^^
}
bool Node::hasParent() {
    return (Parent != nullptr);
}
size_t Node::NodeID() {
    return _nodeID;
}
```

Comment: can it be some circular dependency?

Comment: My thought as well, maybe post the implementation of hasParent so we have a bit more context ?

Comment: Echoing other people, this seems like you have a cycle somewhere formed from the parent pointers. Have you considered printing out what child is at each point in time?

Comment: Is there a reason? Yes, there is. Did you try running your code under a debugger to investigate, what it is?

Comment: I tried that. The parent and child have the same id and everything. I can't understand why they are the same, though. Hopefully we can get tot he bottom. I know it is kick yourself in the face simple. But for the life of me, lol..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm ALWAYS in debug hue hue (when testing)

Comment: @BjarneStroustrup I wasn't asking if you are compiling in debug configuration. I was asking if you ran your code under a debugger, and stepped through it, step-by-step, to investigate where your code derails from your expectations?

Comment: Well step-through is useful for me elsewhere, but here, I can follow what is happening OK, it's probably just something like a pointer assignment detail or something stupid. *Giving it a try anyway*

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Stepping through it didn't reveal anything. Only that the 'getPadding' loop seemingly always reads 'child' as having a parent. (which I found out is a pointer to itself!)

Comment: @BjarneStroustrup Did you step through the _whole_ code? What about stepping through the method where node gets created (and I assume, where parent is created). If it was _something like a pointer assignment detail_, you would catch it by stepping through your code, and investigating variable values at each step. This is what every developer does to investigate bugs in the code - uses a debugger. If you don't know how to use it - please look for tutorials on the internet - there are plenty of those, since SO is not tutorial-service site.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I've ran through every step (vector methods inclusive), and within my ability, I cannot find any 'loopholes'. I will leave the question in case it gets answered, until I figure it out myself.

Comment: @BjarneStroustrup 1) You weren't thorough enough when debugging your code. 2) It would be very hard to answer your question without [mcve] - keyword "complete".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten the classes a little, and I'll leave it here in case anyone else has any trouble with this.

AST.h

---

```
enum TokenType { 
...  
STRING_LIT,
INT_LIT
...
}
struct AST;
struct Node {
    TokenType Type;
    string Data;
    size_t ID;
    AST* ParentAST;
    size_t ParentID;
    vector<Node>* Children();
    bool hasParent();
    bool hasChildren();
    string tokenTypeString();
    size_t getPaddingLen();
};
struct AST {
    vector<Node> Nodes;
    void addNode(Node node);
    void addNode(Node node, size_t parent);
    Node& getNodeWithID(size_t nodeID);
    void printAST();
};
```

AST.cpp

---

```
#ifndef _AST_H
#include "AST.h"
#endif

//**C AST
void AST::addNode(Node node) {
    //Edit node data and add to AST
    node.ID = Nodes.size() + 1;
    node.ParentAST = this;
    node.ParentID = NULL;
    Nodes.push_back(node);
}
void AST::addNode(Node node, size_t parent) {
    //Edit node data and add to parent node
    node.ID = Nodes.size() + 1;
    node.ParentAST = this;
    (parent != NULL) ? node.ParentID = parent : node.ParentID = NULL;
    Nodes.push_back(node);
}
Node& AST::getNodeWithID(size_t nodeID) {
    //Search for node with specified ID in Nodes
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Nodes.size(); i++) {
        if (Nodes[i].ID == nodeID) return Nodes[i];
    }
}
void AST::printAST() {
    //Return if there are no nodes
    if (Nodes.size() == 0) return;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Nodes.size(); i++){
        cout << StringManip::repeatString(".", Nodes[i].getPaddingLen()) << Nodes[i].tokenTypeString() << "\n";
    }
}

//**C Node
vector<Node>* Node::Children() {
    vector<Node>* ret = new vector<Node>;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ParentAST->Nodes.size(); i++)
        if (ParentAST->Nodes[i].ParentID == /*this->*/ID)
            ret->push_back(ParentAST->Nodes[i]);
    return ret;
}
bool Node::hasParent() {
    return (ParentID != NULL);
}
bool Node::hasChildren() {
    return (Children()->size() != 0);
}
string Node::tokenTypeString() {
    //Return string based on which TokenType the node has
    switch (Type) {
        ...
    case TokenType::STRING_LIT:
        return "STRING_LIT";
        break;
        ...
    default:
        return "UNKNOWN_TOKEN";
    }
}
size_t Node::getPaddingLen() {
    size_t ret = 0;
    Node* curr_node = this;
    while (curr_node->hasParent()) {
        //Add the length of the type string to the returned value
        ret += ParentAST->getNodeWithID(curr_node->ParentID).tokenTypeString().length();
        //Set curr_node to its parent
        curr_node = &ParentAST->getNodeWithID(curr_node->ParentID);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And a simple (nonsensical) implementation

---

```
AST ast;
Node node;

node.Type = TokenType::INT_LIT;
node.Data = "76534";
ast.addNode(node);
node.Type = TokenType::STRING_LIT;
node.Data = "hello world";
ast.addNode(node, 1);
node.Type = TokenType::STRING_LIT;
node.Data = "another string";
ast.addNode(node, 2);
node.Type = TokenType::INT_LIT;
node.Data = "9777";
ast.addNode(node);

ast.printAST();
```